# Low volume problems Asus Xonar DX

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

I have problems with my sound card, an Asus Xonar DX on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. To hear something, i need to set Ubuntu's volume at 100% and speakers volume at 75%.

[image: Ubuntu sound]
[image: alsamixer]

At this moment i can barely  hear something with some quality. But then, at the moment when I increased volume, like a 10% more, it sounds distorted.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Try to re-plug the extra power connector.

Comment: **Takkat** Thx for the editting. @CL. That's it! The plastic part had moved like 1/2 inch and did not allow that the connection would fit properly. Fixed!!!

Comment: @CL. please post your solution as an answer, then Xaver can accept it, you get your reputation, and this question can be closed properly ;)

Comment: Solved. The connector did not fit properly.